# error -Didn't find class "android.support.v4.widget

Tags: android

this is my main activity.xml

`

```
          <android.support.v4.widget.
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <FrameLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="match_parent">


            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"/>

        </FrameLayout>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment.navigation.drawer"
            android:name="piestudio.zine.NavigationDrawerFragment"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"/>



    </android.support.v4.widget.>



</LinearLayout>
```

`

main activity.java

`    package piestudio.zine;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.drawer,menu);
        return true;
    }

    public android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_appbar);

        toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);



       NavigationDrawerFragment drawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
               getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUP(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer,(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout),toolbar);}



}
```

`

navigation drawer activity

`    package piestudio.zine;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "testpref";
    public static final String KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER="user_learned_drawer";
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private View containerView;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;


    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {


        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       mUserLearnedDrawer=Boolean.valueOf(readFromPreferences(getActivity(),KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER,"false"));
        if(savedInstanceState!=null){

            mFromSavedInstanceState=true;
        }


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);

    }


    public void setUP(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, final Toolbar toolbar) {
        containerView=getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);

        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);

                if (mUserLearnedDrawer){
                    mUserLearnedDrawer=true;
                    saveToPreferences(getActivity(),KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER,mUserLearnedDrawer+"");
                }

                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();


            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                if (slideOffset<0.8){
                toolbar.setAlpha(1-slideOffset);}
            }
        };

        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer&&!mFromSavedInstanceState){


            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(containerView);

        }
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();

            }
        });


    }


    public static void saveToPreferences(Context context, String preferenceName, String preferenceValue) {

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(preferenceName, preferenceValue);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static String readFromPreferences(Context context, String preferenceName, String defaultValue) {

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(preferenceName,defaultValue);
    }

}
```

`

logcat of error

`Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136)
                                                                      at piestudio.zine.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.widget." on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/piestudio.zine-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/piestudio.zine-1, /system/lib]]
                                                                      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
                                                                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
                                                                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136) 
                                                                      at piestudio.zine.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21) 
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133) 
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

my app is not starting and giving me force close everytime i run it in emulator . please help me out . i am doing all this to get items (list) on navigation drawer you can also point out any mistake in the code :). though the logcat is showing the error of ## -Didn't find class "android.support.v4.widget. ## i am not able to solve this error

Answer (score 1):

Add compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0' line  in dependencies block in your build.gradle(Module: app) file.

Answer (score 0):

As I see in your code you are implementing `NavigationDrawer` and you are miss below thing.

The error is display here `<android.support.v4.widget.`

change this  `<android.support.v4.widget.`  to this  `<android.support.v4.widget.NavigationDrawer`

and also change below `</android.support.v4.widget.>` to this `</android.support.v4.widget.NavigationDrawer>`

Comment: did it but 
The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.v4.widget.NavigationDrawer

this is being displayed

Comment: @abhishekatre update your error and changing xml file as i suggest.